# preg_match while the keyword attached to something else

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

Suppose that I have a long string, and I wanna cut it in a way to contain a keyword (the keyword is based on a pattern, like {query:ABCD:1234}), 5 words before the keyword and 5 words after it. If the keyword appears alone, I can find it using this regex:

```
preg_match("/(([^ ]+ ){5})$keyword (([^ ]+ ){5})/", $text, $matches);
```

But if the keyword attached to some other characters (e.g. a comma or dot), the above regex cannot find it. If I change the regex to this one:

```
preg_match("/(([^ ]+ ){5})$keyword(([^ ]+ ){5})/", $text, $matches);
```

It finds the keyword attached to the comma, but not alone.

How can I cover both cases, keyword alone and with attachment, with a regex?

Comment: Try `"/((?:\w+\W+){5})" . preg_quote($keyword, "/") . "((?:\W+\w+){5})/"`

Comment: if `$keyword` literally contains a dot `.` then it will be interpolated as the wildcard regex char so it will match any single char. It sounds like you need to use `preg_quote()` like this `preg_match("/(([^ ]+ ){5})".preg_quote($keyword, "/")." (([^ ]+ ){5})/", $text, $matches);` so that you perform a literal match instead of getting interpreted as a regex reserved char.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
preg_match("/((?:\w+\W+){5})" . preg_quote($keyword, "/") . "((?:\W+\w+){5})/", $text, $matches);
```

The pattern will now  match:

- `((?:\w+\W+){5})` - Group 1: five occurrences of any 1+ word chars followed with 1+ non-word chars
- `preg_quote($keyword, "/")` - a `$keyword` text with all special chars and the regex delimiter escaped
- `((?:\W+\w+){5})` - Group 2: five occurrences of any 1+ non-word chars followed with 1+ word chars

Comment: what if the word attached to a dot or question mark? Looks like it does not work in this case, like "$keyword Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet!". It will consider amet, but not amet!

Comment: @Belkin Please showcase the issue [here](https://regex101.com/r/KOo8Ml/1) and let know what you expect.

Comment: Original: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris consequat, quam id feugiat varius {query:ABCD:1234}.
  
I expect 
    ... quam id feugiat varius {query:ABCD:1234}.

But it returns:
    ... quam id feugiat varius {query:ABCD:1234}
(No dot at the end).


    Original: {query:ABCD:1234} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet!
    Returns: {query:ABCD:1234} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ...
    Expected: {query:ABCD:1234} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet!

Comment: @Belkin Ok, I see you posted [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59002335/preg-match-considers-special-characters-as-a-separate-word)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to Wiktor Stribiżew, this regex will fix it:

```
"/((?:\w+\W+){5})" . preg_quote($keyword, "/") . "((?:\W+\w+){5})/"
```